# What is the meaning of "a year-round population of about 700"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I can't understand the sentence below:

> Most of them live on Isleboro, which has a **year-round population** of about 700

does it mean:

- whole population is 700

or

- their population is increased by 700 each year

Comment: neither. Means there is a population of 700 that stick around the whole year, and an unspecified additional number that are seasonal.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The *year-round population* refers to people who live in a place the whole year. This excludes for example tourists, who stay in a place for a few weeks and then go home again.

For example, [Wikipedia says about Martha's Vineyard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Martha%27s_Vineyard)

> The 2010 census reported a year-round population of 16,535 residents, (...) although the summer population can swell to more than 100,000 people.

Comment: "Year round population" also excludes people who would be considered part-time residents, such as those who own a home there, but only stay for half the year.

Comment: Would only those persons be included in this number who stay (almost) all year? Or would this more likely be the minimum population number during a timespan of one year? - There could be places which are inhabited year-round, but never by the same persons for a full year... Would they have a year-round polulation of zero?

Comment: @I'mwithMonica To my knowledge, "year-round population" refers to the people who stay (almost) all year. A hypothetical place where people come and go all the time, but _nobody_ stays all year round, would habe a year-round population of zero.

Answer (score 10):

Certain areas though may have a much greater seasonal variance in population, such as tourist areas. The "year-round" population would include only those who are mainly resident for the entire year, and not the transient population.

Comment: Another example is college towns that become depopulated during summer breaks.

Comment: And agricultural areas during picking season

Comment: @dan04 Or college football stadiums.  During sellout games, University of Nebraska's football stadium is the third largest city in the state.

Answer (score 4):

The normal population is 700. The population probably grows temporarily during the tourist season, which I assume is summer. When the tourist season is over, the population returns to 700.

Comment: The OP's quoted passage is from a Stuart Woods novel, in which Islesboro is located in Maine. So you are correct that the tourist season would be summer.